# How do I detect when a telnet client is improperly closed to a tcp server?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I am experimenting in creating a small IRC server to learn some new programming concepts (and others I haven't used in forever).  The first step is to get a basic client connecting via TCP to send plaintext commands to the server.

To listen for connection I have the following code:

```
public NetworkClient(Server server, TcpClient socket, int id)
{
    _socket = socket;
    _id = id;
    _server = server;
}

private async void ListenForClients()
{
    int numClients = 0;
    while (IsRunning)
    {
        var tcpClient = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        var netClient = new NetworkClient(this, tcpClient, numClients);
        netClient.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");

        numClients++;
    }
}
```

Then in my `NetworkClient` class my `Start()` method looks like:

```
public async void Start()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(_socket.GetStream()))
    {
        while (_server.IsRunning)
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} wrote: {1}", _id, line);
        }
    }
}
```

This works well while a telnet client is connected, however once I close my telnet client `reader.ReadLineAsync();` constantly returns `null`.  I would add a check to see if `line == null` but I'm not sure that is the correct way to detect if a client has disconnected.

To make matters worse, `_socket.Connected` is constantly returning true all while nulls are getting "received" by `reader.ReadLineAsync()`.

What is the proper way to detect when tcp clients have been disconnected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A read on a TCP/IP socket will return 0 bytes when the connection has been gracefully closed. [This situation causes `ReadLineAsync` to return `null`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync.aspx) So, yes, you should check for `null` and treat it as a graceful socket closure.

Sockets may be closed other ways, too; any socket operation may throw an exception if the socket is abortively closed. If the exception happens at an acceptable part of the protocol (where a close is not considered an error), then you should treat that exception as though it were a graceful closure as well.

Oh, and `TcpClient.Connected` (like `Socket.Connected`) is practically useless; [it only tells you whether the socket *was* connected, not whether it *is* connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx). Just pretend that property doesn't exist.

Finally, a couple of notes:

- Avoid `async void`. If your methods return `Task`, then you have a "handle" to see when they complete (and whether they raised exceptions). My [recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) explains why `async void` is not recommended.
- It's best to periodically send data over the connection to determine if it is still viable. I wrote a [TCP/IP .NET sockets FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that [covers this in more detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the resources as well!  I'm new to both `async/await` and sockets, so those will definitely come in handy.